# How to find the element which contains a specific sub-element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, webdriver

My webpage contains several `<frame>`. And I need to find the frame which contains `//a[@id='edit']`.

So I tried `//frame[//a[@id='edit']]` but this xpath return 0 element.

```
<frame>
    ...
</frame>
<frame>
    #document
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            ...
            <a id='edit'>Edit</a>   <!-- Added closing tag -->
            ...
        </body>
    </html>
</frame>
<frame>
    ...
</frame>
```

Any idea?

Comment: To complete zx485's answer, adding a "." to the request should be enough `//frame[.//a[@id='edit']]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) i.e. inline frame is a construct which embeds a document into an HTML document so that embedded data is displayed inside a subwindow of the browser's window. This does not mean full inclusion and the two documents are independent, and both them are treated as complete documents, instead of treating one as part of the other. Hence you can't identify an `<iframe>` element through it's descendants.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)

---

### Solution

As a solution you have to construct a [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based on the `<iframe>` attributes.

> You can find a couple of detailed discussions in [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/how-to-switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `descendant-or-self::` axis like this:

```
//frame[descendant-or-self::a[@id='edit']]
```

The result is the second `<frame>` element.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if is it working with selenium? Or if I have to switch in the frame before?

Comment: It is an XPath-1.0 solution, so it should work with Selenium.